# Stuck at Step 0 of using LibTooling and LibASTMatchers

Tags: git, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to follow the tutorial in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html and I am stuck at step 0.

I am running the command

```
git checkout next
```

and I get the `error: pathspec 'release' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Please help

Comment: That's definitely odd: `git checkout next` has no pathspec, and Git won't allow you to create an alias for a built-in command like `git checkout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a package manager of your choice, homebrew on macOS for example, to install ninja directly.